# Duplicate row above on multiple lines

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I want to be able to make a selection in Excel, then run a macro that will duplicate the above row in to all the rows below.

This:

[image]

Would become:

[image]

I can do this for just one row using CTR + D, but I want to be able to do it for 100s of rows at a time with a macro.

My starting point was this:

```
Sub DuplicateRow()
    Selection.FillDown
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need a macro? Select the source row you want to copy, Copy (Ctrl+C) then select the destination area, Paste (Ctrl+V), and it's done.

Comment: yeah as simple as that sounds the end user of the report is VERY basic, so trying to eliminate as many manual steps as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do it with VBA macro:

```
   Sub CopyDown()
    Selection.Rows(1).Offset(-1, 0).Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
   End Sub
```